# Python ignores file type when creating file

Tags: python, datetime, file-type

I'm trying to create a .txt file with some data, and I want the file name to be the current time. But when I run my code it creates an empty file instead, without any file-type. Here is the code in question:

```
filename = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M')

with open('%s.txt' % filename, 'w') as open_file:
    # writing to file
```

It seems to ignore the ".txt" part because if i write the code like this it works just fine:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as open_file:
```

Comment: What OS are you on? `:` is not a valid character in a filename on some platforms.

Comment: change it to `with open('{f}.txt'.format(f=filename), 'w') as open_file:`

Comment: What is the value of the variable ‘filename’ ? Can you print it?

Comment: @steelberg: Also, you say "It seems to ignore the ".txt" part". What does that mean exactly? Do you get a filename with exactly the value of the `filename` variable, but without `.txt`? (I find that hard to believe.) Or do you mean something different?

Comment: If you are on windows the issue is the ":" in the filename.  As you can see from the filename created it stops right before :

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even realize that `:` could be the culprit, solved.

Comment: Yeah i just got a bland file with `filename` except it stopped after the `:` and i didnt notice.

Comment: @steelberg: If you've found the solution to your problem, you can add an *answer* below and accept it to show that the question is resolved.

Comment: @DanielPryden Cant accept own answer within 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows, you cant use `:` in the filename. It stops the creation of the file when it reaches the colon.

Answer (score 1):

It runs fine on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04  and python 3.5)

```
import datetime
import time
filename = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M')

with open('%s.txt' % filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write('code written')
```

please provide more info

And yes i am getting .txt in my file name

Comment: It's windows naming conventions. I didn't think about not using `:` in the filename.

Comment: Yeah i saw your and other guys comment in your question. I wans't of much help though